# How to convert binary floating points to decimal fractions?

Tags: assembly, binary, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm stuck on a homework assignment; I need to convert a binary float to a decimal fraction. I feel like I understand the process, but I'm not getting the right answer. Here's my thought process.

I have the binary float:  `0 000 101`

- The bias for a 3-bit exponent field is 3: `2^(3-1)-1 = 3`
- The mantissa becomes `1.101` (base 2)
- The value of the exponent bits, 0, minus the number of exponent bits, 3, is -3, so the decimal of the mantissa gets moved left 3 places
  `0.001101`
- In base-10, that is `2^-3 + 2^-4 + 2^-6`, which equals 0.203125 or 13/64.

However, 13/64  is not the correct answer, the auto-grader doesn't accept it. If my answer is wrong, then I don't understand why, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

By pure luck I guessed 5/32 as the answer and got it correct; I have no idea why that's the case.

Comment: what does it say the right answer is?

Comment: another way to look at this 0.001101 right or wrong is the same as 1101/2^6 or 13/64. so your exponent must be wrong?  knowing the right answer should sort that out yes?

Comment: By pure luck I guessed 5/32 as the answer and got it correct; I have no idea why that's the case

Comment: Perhaps the format doesn't have a hidden leading 1 bit? Then the mantissa is 1.01 and the value is 1.01 x 2^-3 which is 5/32.

Comment: Did your homework assignment tell you that this was an IEEE754 style of format?  IDK if there are others that use a biased exponent but have a different meaning for denormals.  (Your question already makes it clear that you are using a biases exponent the way IEEE754 does, so it can't be a completely different format.  Fun fact: C doesn't require that FP types use IEEE formats at all.  But you tagged this `[assembly]`, so I guess it's for a teaching ISA with 7 bit IEEE-style floats?  That's odd, why not 8-bit IEEE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat?)

Comment: We have two different assignments, one for 7 bit floats and one for 8 bits. I figured I'd start with the 7 bits. The homework doesn't mention anything about different formats; I'm brand new to this stuff, but I know we'll be writing ARM64 instructions later in the semester, I don't know if that makes more sense.

Comment: @Grav: Yeah, 8 and 7 bit float make sense to teach you about the format.  Sound like a good approach.  But hopefully your class learned something about FP formats that included denormals!  Otherwise this is real gotcha assignment. :P  But yes, ARM64 uses the IEEE754 floating point, exactly like you're learning here.  (Fun fact, ARM NEON (simd vectorized floating point) doesn't support denormals: it flushes them to zero.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html).  Apparently ARM64 does support an IEEE fp16 format: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half-Precision.html

Comment: @prl: Good idea, that would also explain it.  If we knew the value of any other bit patterns, (with a non-zero exponent), we could tell whether this was an explicit-1 "pseudo-denormal" or a hidden-bit denormal.  (@Grav: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format for a detailed bit-diagram and table for a floating point format that has an explicit leading bit.  Specifically, the 80-bit format used internally by legacy x87 floating point instructions, and as `long double` in some C implementations on x86.  For example, gcc)

Comment: There are other ways to represent the same value which would be more canonical than a zero exponent field but leading bit set in the mantissa.  At least in the x87 case, for pseudo-denormals, wikipedia says.  "The 80387 and later properly interpret this value but will not generate it."  So again, it's still a corner case for the format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IEEE-754 floating-point formats, **`exponent = 0` is a denormal, where the implied leading bit in the mantissa is 0**.

Wikipedia has a good detailed article on the [single-precision `float` (binary32)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format, with lots of examples.  For binary32 float, the formulas are (from the wiki article):

```
(−1)^signbit × 2^(−126)        × 0.significandbits   ; denormal, expbits=0
(−1)^signbit × 2^(expbits−127) × 1.significandbits   ; normal
 Inf  or  NaN (depending on mantissa aka significant); expbits = all 1s
```

(Note that 0.0 is a special case of denormal, but is not actually considered a denormal).

Anyway, with zero exponent, notice that the exponent is no longer `expbits - bias`, it's one higher.

---

Back to your case: your mantissa is 0.101 binary, 0.625 decimal (I plugged `0b101 / 8` into `calc`).

2^-2 * `0.101`(binary) = 2^-2 * 0.625(decimal) = 0.15625 = 5/32

---

There's a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat wikipedia article, which mentions (with examples) an 8-bit IEEE format, as well as some other less-than-32-bit formats used in real life on computer-graphics hardware.  (e.g. 24-bit or 16-bit).  Fun fact: x86 can load/store vectors of 16-bit half-precision floats, converting to/from single in registers on the fly with the [F16C ISA extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F16C).

See also this online converter with check-boxes for bits: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html